# Blender 2.90 - Bevel node not working at all

Tags: bevel

I use blender 2.90 , I create a simple shader, add a **bevel** node and it has just no effect at all

I tried outputting it to **base color**, and to node wrangler **viewer** node

I do this under cycles renderer in shaded mode

nothing seems to be working

**I expect it to blur the normal on the edges**

thanks

[image]

Comment: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/input/bevel.html#bevel-node Cycles only and you re showing viewport shading.

Comment: I mentioned using cycles and using shaded view

Comment: ok it works in render preview with low values

Comment: if bigger values, increase the samples to have better result

Comment: apparently it's only meant to work in render preview

Comment: I tried pointiness from geometry, is it only under cycles too ? cos I get zero result with it

Comment: Maybe you can read the documentation by yourself, don't you think? Have indicated a link which is close to what you ask in the first comment.

Comment: well I cant read

Answer (score 3):

I was also stuck a same thing, but when I **changed the viewport** (press <kbd>Z</kbd>) to **Render (with Cycles)**, the bevel node was working.

Your viewport is material preview. So, unless you change the viewport to render, you can not realize the bevel node working.